# Ncurses x value capped

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I am writing an Ncurses app, and I noticed this strange behaviour. When I write some text, the characters are capped to 60. I don't believe this is specific to my terminal emulator as I tried 3 others on my machine, and even xterm did not work. On xterm it was capped to 78 characters.

I've found the x caps for different terminal emulators by printing the getmaxyx values on the screen.
I don't really know how to fix this, the app works fine besides that.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  initscr();
  int mx, my;
  getmaxyx(stdscr, my, mx);
  
  attron(A_STANDOUT);
  mvprintw(0,0, "Example app");
  attroff(A_STANDOUT);
  
  if (argc==2) {
    mvprintw(1,0, argv[1]);
  } else {
    endwin();
    exit(1);
  }
  mvprintw(1,10, "%d, %d", mx, my);
  char ch;
  int counter;
  int printy = 1;
  while (1) {
    ch = getch();
    // doesen't get executed which is all right
    // TODO
    if (0) {
      endwin();
      exit(0);
    } else {
      if (counter+1>my) {
    printy++;
    counter = 0;
      }
      mvprintw(printy, counter, keyname(ch));
      counter++;
    }
  }
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Unless your program calls `cbreak` or `raw`, the input is *line-buffered*, which can make the relationship between input/output hard to understand.

Comment: `counter+1>my`??? what would it mean? If anything, you need `counter >= mx`.

Answer (score 0):

`counter` is read (`counter + 1`) before it is initialized. This is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), and generally means the rest of your program could do just about *anything*.

That said,

```
counter + 1 > my
```

is comparing a value used to control the *horizontal* printing of characters against the maximum value of the *vertical* space.

It might help if your variable identifiers correlated in some way.

Consider using [`noecho`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/curs_inopts.3x.html). Also note that [`getch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/curs_getch.3x.html) returns an `int`.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int mx, my;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s TITLE\n", *argv);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    initscr();
    noecho();

    getmaxyx(stdscr, my, mx);

    attron(A_STANDOUT);
    mvprintw(0, 0, "Example app");
    attroff(A_STANDOUT);

    mvprintw(1, 0, argv[1]);
    mvprintw(1, 10, "%d, %d", mx, my);

    int input;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 2;

    /* move cursor for user clarity */
    move(y, x);

    while ((input = getch()) != ERR) {
        if (x >= mx) {
            y++;
            x = 0;
        }

        mvprintw(y, x++, keyname(input));
    }

    endwin();
}
```